# How to dispatch action in event handler in React & Redux application

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux

My code is here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-8g3p3l

There are 2 *dumb components*:

- insertion_citylist.jsx with the following code:
- insertion_shoplist.jsx with the following code:

I expect the change on the selected city from the `inseriton_citylist.jsx` will trigger change on the shop list in `insertion_shoplist.jsx`. So my *container component*, `app.js` contains a function `findShops`, where the action `shoplist(city)` is called.

My container component code, `app.jsx`, is the following:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { citylist, shoplist } from "../actions";
import { bindActionCreators } from "redux";
import CityList from "../components/insertion_citylist";
import ShopList from "../components/insertion_shoplist";

class App extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    console.log("mount");
    this.props.citylist();
    this.props.shoplist();
  }

  findShops(city) {
    console.log("findShops:", city);
    this.props.shoplist(city);
  }

  /* renderShops = shops =>
    shops
      ? shops.map(shop => <option key={shop.id} value={shop.name} />)
      : null; */
  render() {
    console.log("render:" + this.props);
    return (
      <div>
        <CityList data={this.props.data} findShops={this.findShops.bind(this)} />
        <ShopList {...this.props} />
        {/* <input list="shop" placeholder="shop" />
        <datalist id="shop">
          {this.renderShops(this.props.shop_data.shops)}
        </datalist> */}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  console.log("map state to props:" + state.shops);
  return { data: state.insertion_data }; //Use of spread operator: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NCwa_xi0Uuc&t=1721s
  //return { city_data: state.cities, shop_data: state.shops };
};

const mapDispathToProps = dispatch => {
  console.log("map dispatch to props");
  return bindActionCreators({ citylist, shoplist }, dispatch);
};

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispathToProps
)(App);
```

The `findShops` can be called successfully when the city from the downdown list is changed, but seems that the `this.props.shoplist()` just called the action without calling the *reducer*. And the actions code from `actions/index.js` looks like this:

```
export function citylist() {
  return { type: "CITY_LIST", payload: [{city:"Berlin"}, {city: "Frankfurt"}] };
}

export function shoplist(city) {
  let data = [{name:"original"},{name:"original 2"}];
  if (city === 'Frankfurt') data=[{name:"new"},{name:"new 2"}];
  return {
    type: "SHOP_LIST",
    payload: data
  };
}
```

*Problem*: The current code is able to trigger the event handler `findShops()`, but does not succeed in changing the city list `state` and thus the city list on the `insertion_citylist.jsx` just keeps unchanged all the while. Could anyone help on this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So, with not succeeding, what do you mean? Do you get an error? I am a bit curious in how you are expecting `findShops` to work, you are only getting the deconstructing `data` from the props passed in, but you are not getting `findShops`, so do you get an error like `cannot call something undefined`

Comment: Can you create stackblitz link to reproduce the issue?

Comment: I did not get error. The action function `shoplist(city)` is invoked successfully in event handler `findShops`, but the *reducer* did not work so the shop list on the page did not change

Comment: @Justcode thanks a lot for the suggestion, I moved the code to stackblitz :) https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-8g3p3l

Comment: Do not move the code, please add essential parts of it here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it turns out very simple issue

```
onChange={(e) => props.findShops(e)}
```

here you are passing e as paramenter

```
findShops(city) {        
    this.props.shoplist(city);
  }
```

and using it directly, this is invalid as you will have event in your city parameter.

you need `e.target.value`

change

```
 <select name="city"
 onChange={(e) => props.findShops(e)}>{renderCities(props.data.cities)}</select>
```

to

```
<select name="city"
 onChange={(e) => props.findShops(e.target.value)}>{renderCities(props.data.cities)}</select>
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-hbd6fb),
 remember react pass an event when you change the value, you need to extract the value when you are reading from it. like you are doing in javascript or jquery.

for checkboxes its `e.target.checked` and for inputs its `e.target.value`.